# WebRTC does not work in Angular 5 on iOS Safari

Tags: ios, angular, safari, webrtc, zonejs

I'm building an app with WebRTC and it's not working in Angular 5 on iOS Safari. I use native WebRTC API, no framework.

#### First without Angular

To prove my point Angular is the problem, I did a WebRTC test with plain html and javascript. So I had an `index.html` and a `my-webrtc.js`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">    
  <title>WebRTC Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <video id="local-video" playsinline autoplay muted></video>
    <video id="remote-video" playsinline autoplay></video>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="js/my-webrtc.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I put those two files on a TSL/SSL secured webserver. On the same server I have a basic signaling server installed. In the `my-webrtc.js` there is everything: signaling, offer, answer, ice candidates and connecting the stream to the HTML elements.

For all the tests I used only the LAN just to make sure no STUN or TURN is needed.

#### Test results

Everything works fine in these tested situations:

- Desktop/Chrome <-> Desktop/Chrome
- Desktop/Chrome <-> Desktop/Firefox
- Desktop/Chrome <-> Desktop/Safari
- Desktop/Chrome <-> Android/Tab/Chrome
- Desktop/Chrome <-> iPhone/Safari
- Desktop/Chrome <-> iPad/Safari
- Desktop/Safari <-> iPhone/Safari
- Desktop/Safari <-> iPad/Safari
- iPad/Safari    <-> iPhone/Safari

#### Specifications of the devices:

Desktop/Chrome
- Macbook MacOS 10.12.6
- Chrome 64.0.3282.140

Desktop/Firefox
- Macbook MacOS 10.12.6
- Firefox 58.0.1

Desktop/Safari
- Macbook MacOS 10.12.6
- Safari 11.0.3

Android/Tab/Chrome
- Samsung Galaxy Tab3 8.0 inch (SM-T310)
- Android 4.4.2
- Chrome 64.0.3282.137

iPad/Safari
- iPad mini 2 (A1489)
- iOS 11.2.5
- Safari

iPhone/Safari
- iPhone 6 (A1586)
- iOS 11.2.5
- Safari

After that I did another test leaving the `adapter-latest.js` out of the `index.html` and then still all the above tested situations work fine.

#### Now I put everything in Angular

Now I make the next step. I use Angular CLI version 1.6.3 to create a new Angular test app:

```
ng new webrtc-angular-test
```

It generates a new Angular 5.2.3 app. For signaling I need to install `socket.io`:

```
npm install --save socket.io-client@2.0.4
```

For typings in typescript I add:

```
npm install --save @types/webrtc@0.0.22
npm install --save @types/socket.io-client@1.4.32
```

Then in `app.component.html` I put the same as the `index.html`:

```
<video id="local-video" playsinline autoplay muted></video>
<video id="remote-video" playsinline autoplay></video>
```

And in `app.component.ts` I paste everything from `my-webrtc.js`. I had to make some small modifications so the javascript works in typescript. I didn't import any adaptor yet.

Then building it:

```
ng build
```

And copy the content of the `dist` to the same TSL/SSL secured webserver where also the signaling server runs.

#### Test result

It works well in these cases:

- Desktop/Chrome <-> Desktop/Chrome
- Desktop/Chrome <-> Desktop/Safari
- Desktop/Chrome <-> Android/Tab/Chrome
- Desktop/Chrome <-> Desktop/Firefox

After giving permission on iOS localStream is visible. When the `RTCPeerConnection` is established the remoteStream is normal visible on iOS and almost at the same time the localStream freezes. No error messages in the console. On the Desktop side everything is normal. If two iOS devices are involved, on both side localStream freezes. This happens in these cases:

- Desktop/Chrome <-> iPhone/Safari
- Desktop/Chrome <-> iPad/Safari
- Desktop/Safari <-> iPhone/Safari
- Desktop/Safari <-> iPad/Safari
- iPad/Safari    <-> iPhone/Safari

#### Adding the Webrtc Adapter

Then I install the `webrtc-adapter`:

```
npm install --save webrtc-adapter@6.1.1
```

In `app.component.ts` I put a `import 'webrtc-adapter';`

But things get even worse !!

#### Test result

It works well in these cases:

- Desktop/Chrome <-> Desktop/Chrome
- Desktop/Chrome <-> Desktop/Safari
- Desktop/Chrome <-> Android/Tab/Chrome
- Desktop/Chrome <-> Desktop/Firefox

After giving permission on iOS localStream is visible. When the `RTCPeerConnection` is established the remoteStream is normal visible on iOS and almost at the same time the localStream freezes. No error messages in the console. On the Desktop side everything is normal. If two iOS devices are involved, on both side localStream freezes. This happens in these cases:

- Desktop/Chrome <-> iPhone/Safari
- Desktop/Chrome <-> iPad/Safari

LocalStream is visible on both sides, but remoteStream is not visible on both sides. The logging says peerConnection is created. Offer is send/received and answer is send/received. RemoteStream is added but not visible. No Ice Candidates are being send. RTC peer connection state is changed to 'checking'. There are no error messages. The same happens in the following cases:

- Desktop/Safari <-> iPhone/Safari
- Desktop/Safari <-> iPad/Safari
- iPad/Safari    <-> iPhone/Safari

#### My conclusion:

I have a working WebRTC environment, just plain html with javascript. Then I put this into Angular 5 with typescript and it's not working anymore on iOS Safari. This must be a problem with Angular 5, or typescript or a dependency like zone.js.

#### My questions:

Do you agree with my conclusion or do I overlook something?
Who knows what is the problem and knows a solution?

Help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: no errors on the console either?

Comment: @AyushGupta only in case `Desktop/Chrome <-> Desktop/Firefox`, in others cases no error messages in the console.

Comment: Try doing an 'ng build' and then try running from the dist folder, that's static html and js, so should work of some angular component was interfering

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem that occurs after adding the `webrtc-adapter` is caused by `zone.js` and is solved by adding the following line in `polyfills.ts` (if using `angular-cli`)

```
// rtc peer connection patch
import 'zone.js/dist/webapis-rtc-peer-connection';
// getUserMedia patch
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-patch-user-media';
```

You should add this after `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';` that's already in this file.

I dropped an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22697) for the main problem on iOS where localStream freezes.