# Does the iOS service worker handle requests differently to Chrome/FF?

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am adding progressive web app functionality to an existing web application, and came across a curious edge case. In the scenario, I have implemented some pretty standard caching of API endpoints etc, but bypassing the cache on others. On one of these endpoints I bypass, I am initiating/retrieving a video stream which simply passes through the service worker, except it doesn't work on iOS safari (latest) but works fine going through other browsers on various other devices. It works fine on iOS if I disable the service worker. The error is rather nondescript, but my research so far has led me to believe there could be some potential cross-origin issue going on, or the wrong headers are being formed for some reason. This could be a potential server side thing, which makes life slightly trickier since I don't have access to the content store, which is serviced separately to the main backend. This issue is isolated to video format GET requests, other file types and general API calls all work as expected.

If anyone could advise me or point me to some literature/documentation on how safari+iOS deals with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing might be a [WebKit- Service worker bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=184447).. try with a polifil, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48751342/1057093) if it mattes your format.

Or it might be because of the way response comes. [Try fetching the byte range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52088073/1057093) to prevent Safari reject the response processing.

[Here is another article](https://philna.sh/blog/2018/10/23/service-workers-beware-safaris-range-request/) explaining the range issue.